# Limit image inside specific area in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, limit

I have a code that pastes an image over another and increases the size of the image on up arrow key press and vice versa on down arrow key press.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<img id="imgdisplay" width=960 height=540 src="../static/black_background.png" onclick="clickEvent(event);">

<img id="circle" src="../Different Sizes/red_circle_80.png" style="display:none;" onclick="clickEvent(event);">

<p id='X'>0</p>
<p id='Y'>0</p>

<script>
    var size = 80;
</script>

<script>
var x = 0;
var y = 0;
function clickEvent(event) {
    var thecircle = document.getElementById('circle');
    x = event.clientX
    y = event.clientY
    document.getElementById('X').innerHTML = '' + x;
    document.getElementById('Y').innerHTML = '' + y;
    var pastex = x - (circle.width / 2);
    var pastey = y - (circle.height / 2);
    thecircle.style = `position: absolute; top: ${pastey}px; left: ${pastex}px; display: block; overflow: hidden;`;
}
</script>

<script>
document.onkeydown = function(event) {
    var thecircle = document.getElementById('circle');
    event = event || window.event;
    if (event.keyCode == 38) {
        size += 100;
        thecircle.src = `../Different Sizes/red_circle_${size}.png`;
        clickEvent({'clientX': x, 'clientY' : y})
    } else if (event.keyCode == 40) {
        size -= 100;
        thecircle.src = `../Different Sizes/red_circle_${size}.png`;
        clickEvent({'clientX': x, 'clientY' : y})
    }
};
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that if I click just on the border of the background image, the circle will overflow and half of the circle will stick out of the background. It sticks out much more when I click on the border and I click the up arrow on the keyboard multiple times to enlarge the circle.

How would I limit that the circle would not stick out of the background and not let the user to enlarge the circle if it's already almost sticking out of the background?

What I mean in images are.

### What I currently have and it's not what I want:

[image]

### What I want (to limit it to not stick out of the black background image):

[image]

How would I do this?

Any help appreciated!

Comment: You'll need to do a boundary check. Grab the width and height of the black image, or whatever the element is, and its x/y position. If the circle is beyond X+width (or y+height), then limit the result to x+width.

Comment: @Phaelaxz Thanks for your input, the `x` and `y` of the circle or the mouse press? Maybe it would be nice if you could provide an answer :)

Comment: I would advice to look into CSS a little bit. If the background is just black, you're better off using a black background in CSS on a <div> or <p> containing your <img>, so that the image is actually inside the element having the background, which would make positioning easier. CSS also has a scale property, which can remove the need to use and script multiple different circle images.

Comment: @Shilly I am using a black image for this example, but actually the image is a saved frame from a video...

Comment: I didn't account for dynamic changes in size. Same basic concept though. When you change the size, redo the boundary checks. So if the circle grows when its on the edge, it should bump it over to stay within the box.

Comment: @Phaelaxz I am a newbie in JS and HTML, so a code would help :)

Comment: Give it a try yourself first, it's how you're going to learn.

Comment: @Phaelaxz Ok I try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the solution I was talking about.  The one drawback is this doesn't account for scrolling, but that should be a trivial fix if that is an issue for your case.

```js
var size = 80;

var x = 0;
var y = 0;
function clickEvent(event) {
    var thecircle = document.getElementById('circle');
    x = event.clientX
    y = event.clientY
    
    var box = document.getElementById('imgdisplay');
    
    if (x > box.x+box.width - circle.width / 2){
        x = box.x + box.width - circle.width / 2;
     }
      
    if (y > box.y + box.height - circle.width / 2){
        y = box.y+box.height - circle.width / 2;
    }
    
    if (x < box.x + circle.width/2)
      x = box.x + circle.width/2;
    
    if (y < box.y + circle.width/2)
      y = box.y + circle.width/2;
    
    document.getElementById('X').innerHTML = '' + x;
    document.getElementById('Y').innerHTML = '' + y;
    var pastex = x - (circle.width / 2);
    var pastey = y - (circle.height / 2);
    

    
    thecircle.style = `position: absolute; top: ${pastey}px; left: ${pastex}px; display: block; overflow: hidden;`;
}
```

```css
#imgdisplay{background:black}
#circle{width:80px;height:80px;background:red;border-radius:40px;}
```

```html
<img id="imgdisplay" width=500 height=300 src="../static/black_background.png" onclick="clickEvent(event);">

<img id="circle" src="../Different Sizes/red_circle_80.png" style="display:none;" onclick="clickEvent(event);">

<p id='X'>0</p>
<p id='Y'>0</p>
```

Comment: Hi Phaelex z. I am still able to cross the boundaries on the left and top side of my image... Could you stop it from doing that as well?

Comment: I updated the snippet with the lower boundary checks.

Comment: Thanks very much, upvoted it. But there is still a problem when I click the up arrow, it still gets out of the border

Answer (score 0):

your problem was that the circle had position absolute and not position relative.
Take a look at my example, it works.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
   <style>
     .container{
       z-index: 90;
       overflow: hidden;
       width:450px;
       height: 540px;
       background-image: url("data:image/jpeg;base64,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");
     }

     #circle{
       display: inline-block;
       overflow: hidden !important;
       display: none;
       max-width: 100%;
       max-height:100%;
       z-index: 1;
     }
   </style>
 </head> 
<body>
<div class="container" onclick="clickEvent(event);">
 <!-- <img id="imgdisplay" width=960px height=540px src="" onclick="clickEvent(event);"> -->
  <img id="circle" src="data:image/png;base64,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" onclick="clickEvent(event);">
</div>
<p id='X'>0</p>
<p id='Y'>0</p>

<script>
    var size = 80;
</script>

<script>
var x = 0;
var y = 0;
function clickEvent(event) {
    var thecircle = document.getElementById('circle');
    x = event.clientX
    y = event.clientY
    document.getElementById('X').innerHTML = '' + x;
    document.getElementById('Y').innerHTML = '' + y;
    var pastex = x - (circle.width / 2);
    var pastey = y - (circle.height / 2);
    thecircle.style = `position: relative; top: ${pastey}px; left: ${pastex}px; display: block; overflow: hidden;`;
}
</script>

<script>
document.onkeydown = function(event) {
    var thecircle = document.getElementById('circle');
    event = event || window.event;
    if (event.keyCode == 38) {
        size += 100;
        thecircle.src = `../Different Sizes/red_circle_${size}.png`;
        clickEvent({'clientX': x, 'clientY' : y})
    } else if (event.keyCode == 40) {
        size -= 100;
        thecircle.src = `../Different Sizes/red_circle_${size}.png`;
        clickEvent({'clientX': x, 'clientY' : y})
    }
};
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That clips the circle inside the box, I think he just wanted to constrain its boundaries.